# Passing AutoCompleteTextView/EditText data from one activity to another in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**Introduction**

I have a parent activity with 4 sub-activities. I am using Intents for transferring data from the parent activity's AutoCompleteTextView/EditText to the sub-activity. Also, a spinner is used in every sub-activity to switch between the four sub-activities.

**Problem**

So, here is my problem. I am able to access the EditText value from the parent activity only once. I mean, if I opened the first sub-activity, I am accessing the parent's EditText value. Now, if I switch from first to second sub-activity, I can no more to access the EditText value of parent activity.

**What do I want**

I want to access the value of EditText from parent activity in any of the sub-activities ***any number of times*** unless and until I change the editText value in parent activity. How can this be done?

Comment: You can use intent.putExtras for that, whenever navigating from one to another subactivity. Or you can store the value in sharedpreference to access the value anytime anywhere.

Comment: @user3541465 Thanks for pointing me to shared preferences. Works like a charm. Initially tries using intent.putExtras. But no luck. Thanks again